# AngularJs Form not in scope directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive with isolated scope. In the template of the directive i got a form element. Why the form is not in the scope?

```
<form ng-init="setForm(this)">
```

I've tried something like that to catch the form. But didn't work too. The keyword this is the scope, not the form.

Another attempt was to use `$scope.$watch(<myFormName>, function(){}`. Also didn't work.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Check out [ask] and [mcve]. Given what you have provided you are unlikely to receive a quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

On your HTML you name the form:

```
<form name="signup">
```

This should result in a property on your scope using that name

```
scope.signup
```

Its also *possible* that the form hasnt been fully rendered to the page by the time linking a directive happens. Quite common problem using directives and is generally solved using a basic timeout

```
scope.signup
// undefined

$timeout(function () {
    scope.signup
    // defined after initial angular digest
});
```

Comment: I've created a plunker to demonstrate the problem. [click here to see it](http://plnkr.co/edit/nhM4u4d2oE7xUZmCfvWQ?p=preview)